# Ansible command quotes

Tags: command, ansible, quotes

I would like to have the following command integrated in an Ansible playbook task:

`cut -f 1 -d: /etc/passwd | xargs -n 1 -I {} bash -c ' echo -e "\n{}" ; chage -l {}'`.

Any quote inside breaks the whole command. How I can avoid it to make it run the whole string?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can escape them with `\”`

example: `"hello=\"hi\""`

Comment: The existing escape characters in the command (like `\n`) will also need escaping.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Here is the task that works with escaping the quotes:   `- name: Task    shell: 'sudo cut -f 1 -d: /etc/passwd | xargs -n 1 -I {} bash -c "echo -e \"                                                                                      \n{}\"; chage -l {}" >> users-list-{{ansible_hostname}}.log'`

Answer (score 13):

You can simply use the YAML literal block string syntax. In that way you don't need to escape any quotes. Instead, you can pass your shell command as is.

Example:

```
- name: test task
  shell:
      cmd: |
          cut -f 1 -d: /etc/passwd | xargs -n 1 -I {} bash -c ' echo -e "\n{}" ; chage -l {}'
  tags: test
```